# How to export database from Azure with an invalid server name?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have a SQL Server database on Azure that I want to export. On the Windows Azure portal, I select the database. From the dashboard page I select Export and I get the following error:

```
&lt;html version=&#34;-//W3C//DTD XHTML 2.0//EN&#34; xml:lang=&#34;en&#34; xsi:schemaLocation=&#34;http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml2.xsd&#34; xmlns=&#34;http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml&#34; xmlns:xsi=&#34;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&#34;&gt;&lt;HEAD&gt;&lt;TITLE&gt;Request Error&lt;/TITLE&gt;&lt;/HEAD&gt;&lt;BODY&gt;&lt;DIV id=&#34;content&#34;&gt;&lt;P class=&#34;heading1&#34;&gt;&lt;B&gt;Error Status Code:&lt;/B&gt; &#39;BadRequest&#39;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;P&gt;&lt;B&gt;Details: &lt;/B&gt;Error encountered during the service operation. ; Exception Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.Services.ServiceException:Unsupported Server Name my-server-name.database.windows.net. Please verify that the name has aplha-numeric prefix followed by .database.windows.net; &lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;&lt;/BODY&gt;&lt;/html&gt;
```

Note the encodings are incorrectly displayed `&lt;` rather than <

> **Unsupported Server Name** my-server-name.database.windows.net. Please verify that the name has aplha-numeric prefix followed by .database.windows.net;

My server name only contains alpha characters and a hyphen `-` and starts with an i. Surely the server name is valid otherwise I wouldn't have been able to create the db in Azure originally?

What causes this error? And how can I export my database?

EDIT

I originally created the server instance through the new 'Microsoft Azure' portal which accepts '-'.

[image: azure sql server name validation]

Comment: So, it reads like the tools does not like your hyphens, yes?

Comment: @FelixFrank That is what I'm guessing but it's a bit silly that Azure allows you to create a SQL Server instance knowing you will not be able to export dbs.

Comment: IIRC I originally created the SQL Server instance through the new Microsoft Azure portal so there may be a disparity between server name acceptance.

Comment: Agreed, but it would be feasible - I haven't touched it in a while, but last year the Azure stack did have a couple rough edges left. This may be yet another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a bug within the Azure portals. The new 'preview' portal allows the user to assign set a name for the SQL Server when creating a new database. However the standard portal would automatically assign the server instance a random 10 alphanumeric character name. Therefore some features available in the standard portal expect an alphanumeric name.

To fix this I had to move the databases onto a new SQL server instance with an alphanumeric name. After that the export and backup features worked as expected.

To move the database I used the [SQL Azure Backup](http://www.red-gate.com/dynamic/products/dba/sql-azure-backup/download) tool from RedGate. I had to backup the database to a local instance and then restore it to the new Azure SQL Server instance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the error is but you can use this workaround:

Download sqlpackage.exe util (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx) and add your own IP to allowed IPs via azure management portal.
You can then run something like this:

```
sqlpackage.exe /a:Export /ssn:"yourdb-name.database.windows.net" /sdn:"nameOfYourDB" /su:"user" /sp:"pass" /tf:"C:\backups\db.bacpac"
```

SQL data tools: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027